# When does the Review day begin and end?

Tags: support, review, review-stats

Under `"Your review stats"` on the `/review` page, there is a column for daily stats.  It doesn't seem to follow the standard 0:01 UTC to 0:00 UTC Stack Overflow day (and clear at 0:00 UTC).  I had tried to see if it was a Midnight to Midnight EST or PST day, but I didn't find any conclusive evidence of that.

What span of time does this report follow?

Comment: Yes, I know this isn't something that's pressing, but I'm curious, darnitall.

Comment: the day rolls in review, I may change it so it is consistent with the rest

Answer (score 10, accepted):

At the moment it tracks the previous 24 hours ... I think it is a bit of a bug cause nowhere else on the site does this. Will port it to UTC start of day.

Comment: Did you ever actually port this?

Answer (score 2):

The UTC day rolls over at exactly **7 PM Eastern Standard Time** (EST), 6 PM Central Standard Time (CST), and 4 PM Pacific Standard Time (PST), all these time zones are in the US.  *Note:* These times are *not* during Daylight Savings.

The Daily Review should be following the UTC clock, but it is probably not updating that split second due to caching, etc.

Comment: Yes, I know, but the Daily counter doesn't seem to roll over at that time.

Comment: Ah, entirely possible!  The table itself updates fairly instantaneously, though, even without a page refresh.

Comment: The review clock is VERY off from UTC

Comment: Commenting because relevant.  That's funky.  Is there a particular reason it doesn't just use the specific user's locale and reset at midnight?  Or is it just simplicity/not implemented yet?