# Review Stats is not getting updated

Tags: bug, review, review-stats

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When does the Review day begin and end?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112175/when-does-the-review-day-begin-and-end)

[image]

I havn't reviewed anything today on SO. Though it is showing wrong values. This values are of yesterday. Day counter is not reset to zero.

Is day of last 24 hours or UTC time?

**Update:**

[According to Waffles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112175/when-does-the-review-day-begin-and-end/112195#112195) it is bug. It is not solved until now. We should show day count according to UTC time.

Because some time we keep in mind some goal that I will review 50 posts today. Then it will be misleading. And through out site day structure should be according to UTC time. It is bit confusing.

Is there any other concept of day for last 24 hours?

Comment: UTC time, and it's 8:37 AM UTC right now.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the review stats just looks at the past 24 hours, not the physical day we're on. I've noticed before that the values just decrease by some amount at certain points, back when I did mass reviewing.

Comment: @Yannis: So it is definitely bug. Review stats is showing yesterdays reviewed count for Day.

Comment: @animuson: Big Bang. Is there any source saying about it? Because all stats on community are according to UTC time.

Comment: Now that I think of it I could be wrong on the UTC thing, I review posts every day, for the past 246 days, and I probably stopped noticing the counters after the first couple of days...

Comment: @animuson: [According to Waffles](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/112195/178505) it is bug. So get it reported now. It is not solved until now. We should show day count according to UTC time.

Comment: I don't really care either way. Honestly, the Day stats are fairly useless to me. I only care about the All stats... If you made me choose, I'd rather change the Day to 24Hrs.

Comment: @animuson: Yes surely. Me too. But some time I keep in mind with **To be reviewed**. i.e I set sometimes goal that I will review 50 posts today. Then it will be misleading. And through out site day structure should be according to UTC time. It is bit confusing. Is there any other concept of day for last 24 hours?